# Get Calling Command which pipes into python script

Tags: python, unix, pipe

I have a python script which reads data via pipe like this:

```
cat file.txt | sort | script.py
```

Can I get the calling command `cat file.txt | sort`  as a string in script.py?

Comment: There might be a simpler way, or what I am suggesting might not work, but.... if your Python script looks in `/proc/PROCESSID/cmdline` it can see how it was started itself, so maybe it can look at the most recent (highest PID lower than its own) children of its PARENTPROCESSID and see their commandlines and piece it together. Just a thought.‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call `cat file.txt | sort` from your python script, you could do the following

```
import os
os.sytem("cat file.txt | sort")
```

`os.system()` would return the output from `cat file.txt | sort`.

Hope this is what you are looking for.